# How to Click Parent Element Based on Child Image Element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Selenium to click on a parent web element based on a child image element. Here is a snippet of the elements I'm working with in the page source:

```
<a id="_20_ivtm" href="https://foobar:443/web/baz/document-library?fedit_file_entry">
    <img id="aui_3_2_0_1724" class="icon" style="background-image: url('/foobar/images/document_library/_sprite.png'); background-position: 50% -16px; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 16px; width: 16px;" alt="" src="/foobar/images/spacer.png"/>
    Add Document
```

And I want to click the `a` parent element based on the "Add Document" subtext in its child image element.  I am coding in Java.  Any suggestions as to how to best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text isn't related to the `<img>` tag, it's related to the `<a>` tag.  You can find this like so:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Add Document')]"));
```